HDD is yellow (Caution) in CrystalDiskInfo, Transferred files off of it, but Properties shows 78GB Used Space
HDD is yellow (Caution) in CrystalDiskInfo.. I transferred all visible files off of the hdd, Windows Explorer shows no files on it anymore, but when I open Properties it shows 78GB Used Space.
Is this 78GB corrupted files that are lost? Or were sectors reallocated and no files were lost and this 78GB is just bad sectors with nothing special in them? I have no idea.. so that's my question. Is this 78GB corrupted files? How can I find out what files they are? And how can I recover them (or I'd at least like to see the file names, to see if maybe they're just generic files or programs that are easily replaceable)
I'm trying Recuva now, to see if that will tell me anything about what this 78GB might be. I only did a 'quick scan', but it's taking a very long time. It's in "Step 2 of 3: Analyzing damage". That's the first time I remember ever running Recuva and it be analyzing damage, so something clearly seems wrong with the drive.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In a code box, please post the output of smartctl -a /dev/<disk> via smartmontools

On what system? I'd assume files in trash bin.

bear in mind that the recycle bin is per-user, so even if it looks empty, if there were other users on the local system that might account for some space.

How does the drive appear in WinDirStat, and in a disk management tool? There might be hidden system files.

Thanks for the replies. Recuva quick scan finished and I did see some recoverable files show in recycle bin folder. Not sure if that's the answer yet. I suppose I have to add up all the sizes and see if it equals 78GB.
Disk Management looks normal for this drive.. Simple, Basic, NTFS, Healthy (Basic Data Partition) 99% Free, so same 78GB being used... BUT... I see another disk now looks complete wacky. It's an 18TB disk, shows with 16764.00GB Allocated space, that seems fine, but total space on the left shows 73536164.48GB & 73519400.48GB Unallocated space. Now an 80,000TB hdd lol What?

What should I be looking for in WinDirStat? On the right side it lists only around 600KB of files. JPG 597.1KB 97% of Bytes 3080 filles, with other file types being only 3% and like 17KB and about 140 files, which makes everything nearly no size. Top left, similar, says the same 98.9% of drive free, but only lists $RECYCLE.BIN 100.0% as 615.6KB / 606.4KB Physical/Logical Size 3220 files, all under half a KB. Nothing that adds up to 78.4GB showing as Used Space in Properties and elsewhere.
Really just wondering if those 78.4GB are corrupted/lost files or if it has nothing to do w/ lost files

I went to Options > Show Unknown and there it is.. 78.5GB Physical Size (matches the 78.4GB of 'Used Space', just rounded up likely). 0 Bytes Logical Size, no file number or date listed and the whole bottom half turned yellow.

I searched what others are saying about this Unknown space and a Reddit post suggested running WinDirStat again, but as Administrator.. so doing that, the Unknown Space is now 62.1GB in $RECYCLE.BIN and down to only 16.4GB Unknown. So 80% of my issue is accounted for. 16.4GB could still be a significant amount of documents or images, but going by the rest, I'm just going to call it a day and assume it's just more system files. Thanks everyone who offered ideas. I'm moving forward with confidence, with the assumption that nothing has been lost.

Remember to always verify hidden/system files when checking the disk size. They are hidden by default in many programs. For example, in WinDirStat you need to ensure that Options -> Settings -> Advanced -> Hidden/Protected exclusions are disabled.

An often forgotten place, for example, is recycle bin, as it was in your case. Which is normally on your desktop, so many people think the deleted files are on the system disk. But how it actually works is that each disk/partition stores own files in a folder called $RECYCLE.BIN in the root folder of the partition, then they are combined.

To see the folder and its properties like above, hidden files need to be enabled in Windows Explorer options.
